# What to do to setup a ASP.NET MVC 5 application to work with PrimeVue components?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, bootstrap-vue, primevue

At this moment I have an operating ASP.NET MVC 5 application that works view rich views with a number of JQuery plug-ins. I want to migrate that very same application to Vue, Bootstrap-vue and PrimeVue.

Vue e Bootstrap-vue are already integrated to the application, so a number of views were already rewritten and are working properly. The next step is to add PrimeVue, so the UX will be much improved by taking advantages of the PrimeVue rich components.

My problem is that PrimeVue documentation gives some directions on using Webpack to setup the components, but I have no culture on Webpack. Those directions are stil blurry for me.

What I ask is a roadmap to be able to integrate PrimeVue to my ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper reading I could understand that I can simply add some CSS and JS files publicaly available:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css " rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/primevue.min.css " rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css " rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/components/dropdown/dropdown.umd.min.js"></script>
```

So I simply bundled those CSS and JS files in my app and registered the component in Vue.